# How to force critical battery action in windows?

Tags: windows, laptop, battery

I want to force windows to hibernate when the battery reaches the critical level, because if for an example a video player is playing and the laptop is on battery, it will prevent it from hibernating and deplete the battery and this is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Power Options
Windows key + R, and type in run: powercfg.cpl

Change plan settings>Change advanced power settings

[image]